# mysql what is faster, doing equal equal or not equal

Tags: mysql

Odd question, not sure if it has any relevance

Hypothetically, say a column can only have two values, 0 or 1

which is faster

```
SELECT * FROM `blah` WHERE `column` = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `blah` WHERE `column` != 0
```

assuming that column is of type tinyint

Edit, I know I should be encapsulating the columns/tables in `

Comment: 1. They're both as performant. 2. You forgot about `<>` too ;) 3. You only need to encapsulate them to escape reserved words in MySQL.

Comment: The "equal" is 10^(-10000000000000000000) times faster than with "not equal" because it sends one less byte to MySQL and MySQL parse one less byte.

Answer (score 2):

Equality is the better choice, because it will make better use of an index on `blah(column)`.

If there is no index on the column, then the two would be essentially the same in terms of performance.  However, using equality is a better habit.